# Java MD5 to PHP conversion

Tags: java, php, aes, md5

I have JAVA AES encryption logic

```
private static byte[] getMD5(String input) {
        try {
       byte[] bytesOfMessage = input.getBytes("UTF-8");
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            return md.digest(bytesOfMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

What will be the php equivalent of this function?
I have used md5($string) in php but the output is different in both the cases.

Comment: No,the code is different in both the questions

Comment: Code is different you can take help from that and implement on your code no one will provide you exact code.

Comment: When I do String md5Value = new String(md.digest(bytesOfMessage)) in java; In php it is equivalent to echo md5($str,true); Can you suggest how can I convert md5($str,true) into md.digest(bytesOfMessage)??

Comment: You need Java to PHP OR PHP to Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code that you have posted you get the byte array of the md5 hash. PHP's md5() function returns the md5 hash as a hex.

So, if you want to get the md5 hash as string in java you can like this:

```
private static String getMD5(String input) {
   try {
       byte[] bytesOfMessage = input.getBytes("UTF-8");
       MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
       // byte array of md5 hash
       byte[] md5 = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);
       // we convert bytes to hex as php's md5() would do
       StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
       for (int i = 0; i < md5.length; i++) {
          stringBuffer.append(Integer.toString((md5[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
       }
       return stringBuffer.toString();
   } catch (Exception e) {
   }
   return null;
}
```

From PHP you can get the row md5 binary by doing `md5('some string', true)`. See [md5()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) function documentation about it.

To get the byte array you can do `unpack('c*', md5('some string',true))`. See [unpack()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) function and the possible [formats](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Master_ex..I cant change the Java code..I have to implement a php version of the same code..Can you tell me in java when I pass SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(getMD5(key), "AES");..How can I achieve this in php?...In Java I am getting bytesOfMessage="[B@7b11a3ac"...While in php If I will use unpack as mentioned by you I will get an array..Please suggest

Comment: The bytesOfMessage is an array of bytes. If you try to print it you won't see the contents of the array but as you say you will see something like `[B@7b11a3ac`. However, if you print the values one by one you will get the same content. You can do this like `for(byte b : getMD5(key)) System.out.println(b);`. So, both java and php versions are equivalent. About the SecretKeySpec, apparently it works as you tell that you want to convert Java code to PHP. I suggest you read about [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) library and post a different question if you still have problems.

Comment: Thanks a ton Master_ex...That helped!